# How to resolve conflict during rebase?

Tags: git

I have two branches:

```
  $ git branch
    master
  * readcode
```

I had some changes committed to `master`, so I wanted to bring the changes to `readcode` branch. Then I used rebase:

```
$ git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Health score enhancement.
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging file1
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file1
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 Health score enhancement.

When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
To restore the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".
```

In `file1`, there was a few lines of conflict. I have fixed the conflict in `file1` in the editor. But I found that I was not in `readcode` branch now:

```
$ git branch
* (no branch)
  master
  readcode
```

But I still followed the hint message to do:

```
$ git rebase --continue
file1: needs merge
You must edit all merge conflicts and then
mark them as resolved using git add
```

Then use git add and continue again:

```
$ git add lib/nimbus/loadbalancer/lb.rb
$ git rebase --continue
Applying: Health score enhancement.
No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else
already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this patch.

When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
To restore the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".
```

Which command should I do to tell git that I have resolved the conflict, and continue the rebase?

Comment: As `git rebase` tells you, resolve the conflicts in file1 and run `git add file1`.

Comment: See my update. Still doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like the "Health score enhancement." commit isn't necessary anymore, probably because all of its changes have been applied upstream. Git doesn't want to create commits with no delta. Does `git diff` or `git diff --cached` return any output?

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the output that got posted by the error message? It clearly says that you should use

```
git rebase --continue
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work. See my updated in the question.

Comment: Then there are no changes (verify with `git diff HEAD`) and you can use `git rebase --skip`.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem recently
the reason for this may be that you deleted all the changes you submitted during the conflict resolution presess.

so git thinks there is ***no changes*** and not necessary to generate ***patch***.

so the suggest is use `git rebase --skip`, and the result is your commit that caused the conflict is discarded

You can reproduce the problem locally